# CDMA CD throughput formula connection with Persistence methods

Tags: ethernet, lan

Efficiency for Ethernet (CSMA-CD) is: 1/(1+6.44a), 
where a is ratio of Propagation Delay and Transmission delay
   (from **Data Communication and Networking**  by Forouzan)

I want to connect my understanding of above formula with **1-Persistent**, **P-Persistent** and **Non-Persistent** CSMA CD.

Here is what I think:

1. Since in the derivation of above formula ([a lesson from N. Vlajic](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2010-11/F/3213/CSE3213_13_RandomAccess_2_F2010.pdf)), we use maximized 'p' value to calculate final throughput, **we are able to control** 'p' value and set it in transmitting devices. Thus, it makes sense to call it **P-persistent**.
2. Since maximised 'p' value still gives P(success) = 1/N, we may consider it as **Natural Uniform Probability** even if transmission devices do not have capability of controlling p value. Thus, we may also call it 1-Persistent.

I have no idea about Non-Persistent.

The two deductions (points 1 and 2 above) are rough ideas, what I could reckon. But I am looking for exact and concrete answers.

Also, I've seen 1/(1+5a) formula as well (**Computer Networking** by Kurose and Ross ). Why is this different from above one?

Comment: Homework? ...we don't do homework questions, please read [what can I ask here](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @CraigConstantine Formatted my question. It's not Homework, indeed we are not even taught its derivation.

Comment: all questions related school work are off topic

Answer (score 1):

I believe the formula would apply to all three of the CSMA access modes 1-persistent, P-persistent, and Non-persistent. 1-persistent has low efficiency and low delay. P-persistent has efficiency and delay can be balanced. Non-persistent has high efficiency and high delay. However, all of them use the same formula. [I am referencing a lesson from  N. Vlajic](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2010-11/F/3213/CSE3213_13_RandomAccess_2_F2010.pdf) his lecture handout is very helpful I would suggest reading it because he goes into great detail explaining it.

From what I can tell the Kuros and Ross text is using an aproximation to derive its formula.
[A derivation of the efficiency of Ethernet is beyond the scope of this book (see[Lam 1980]and[Bertsekas 1992]). Here we simply state the following approximation](http://A%20derivation%20of%20the%20efficiency%20of%20Ethernet%20is%20beyond%20the%20scope%20of%20this%20book%20(see[Lam%201980]and[Bertsekas%201992]).%20Here%20we%20simply%20state%20the%20following%20approximation)  the Data Communications and Networking text would seam to have a more accurate formula  (1/1+6.44a).

Comment: This question could be moved to the  [Network Engineering Recommendations Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11177/general-network-engineering-recommendations) if you would still like to get an answer.

Comment: I understand the whole derivation from the referenced note.......

               (I)  Since, in derivation we **use maximized 'p' value** to calculate final throughput, which means, we are **able to control 'p' value** and **set it** in transmitting devices. Thus, it makes sense to call it P-persistent.

           ......(II) Further since maximised 'p' value still gives P(success) = 1/N, which we may consider as **natural uniform probability** even if transmission device does not have capability of controlling p value. Thus, we may also call it 1-Persistent.

<continued>

Comment: I have no idea about Non-Persistent.........

The first two deductions are rough ideas, what I could reckon.
But I am looking for exact answers..........

I don't have enough reputation for Network Engineering Recommendation Chat Room.....

Comment: If you revised your question following the guidelines of the forum as suggested by Mr. Constantine you might be able to get the answer your looking for. He has a link to the "what to ask here" page that could be helpful. Other than that you will have to keep looking for answers because I doubt you'll get a lot more answers after a moderator has commented on your post's validity. Good luck.